# Excel VBA rank by ROW()

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck with Excel VBA to DenseRank rows based on their position or rowID. I included the Sales column below just to show that I'm not concerned with ranking based on a column but rather want to rank by row # and restart the ranking based on when the value changes in column "City".

```
#City#  |#Sales#    |#DESIREDOUTPUT#
Chicago     1           1
Chicago     5           2
Chicago     10          3
Chicago     7           4
New York    3           1
New York    5           2
New York    2           3
```

Sorry, I can't get the table to format correctly.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? That's simple to do with a formula.

Comment: In C2, `=countif(a$2:a2, a2)` and fill down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**formula approach**

put in C1:

```
=IF(A2=A1;C1+1;1)
```

and then drag it down

---

**VBA approach**

```
Sub main()
    With Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
        .Formula = "=if(RC[-2]=R[-1]C[-2],R[-1]C + 1,1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd like the brave downvoter to explain the reason why and let me improve my answer

Comment: PERFECT! I was able to do this, manipulate some of the C and R values and fit it to my dataset in different columns. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on why VBA is necessary but,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(2, "C"), .cells(.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row, "C"))
        .formula = "=countif(a$2:a2, a2)"
        .value = .value
    end with
end with
```